# Error with Varnish child process (failed to map segment from shared object)

Tags: varnish

Varnish child appeared to panic in the early hours of the morning. The following messages were logged to /var/log/messages:

```
Jun 30 00:49:12 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (12025) not responding to CLI, killed it.
Jun 30 00:49:12 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Unexpected reply from ping: 400 CLI communication error (hdr)
Jun 30 00:49:12 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (12025) not responding to CLI, killed it.
Jun 30 00:49:12 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Unexpected reply from ping: 400 CLI communication error
Jun 30 00:49:12 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (12025) died signal=3
Jun 30 00:49:22 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (22758) Pushing vcls failed:#012Could not load compiled VCL.#012#011dlopen(vcl_reload_2019-04-15T110712.1555326432.399262428/vgc.so) = vcl_reload_2019-04-15T110712.1555326432.399262428/vgc.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
Jun 30 00:49:42 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (22758) died signal=6
Jun 30 00:49:45 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (22758) Last panic at: Sun, 30 Jun 2019 00:49:42 GMT#012"Assert error in child_signal_handler(), mgt/mgt_child.c line 296:#012  Condition(Signal 6 (Aborted) received at 0x1f1000058e6 si_code -6) not true.#012errno = 12 (Cannot allocate memory)#012thread = (ban-lurker)#012version = varnish-4.1.9 revision 5024f60c3a51f537279977989b645e983a946e1a#012ident = Linux,4.9.75-25.55.amzn1.x86_64,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit,epoll#012now = 43413242.798650 (mono), 1561855776.431004 (real)#012Backtrace:#012#012"
Jun 30 00:49:48 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (22758) said Child starts
Jun 30 00:49:49 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Child (22758) said libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

After around an hour later, the following was logged:

```
Jun 30 02:06:41 [ip-hidden] varnishd[32140]: Manager got SIGINT
Jun 30 02:06:42 [ip-hidden] varnishd[28097]: Child (28099) said Child starts
```

Uptime from `varnishstat` seems to support this.

It's likely pointless to pontificate on why the child went down in the first place, but would be useful to know why it didn't restart in a timely manner. I suspect a memory issue, but is there realistically anything I can do to prevent this in the future?

For reference, it's version 4.1.9 running on Amazon Linux AMI (2018)